# Data is not display after visiting a page twice

Tags: javascript, durandal

Hi I am building a SPA application using Durandal , knockout and renderjs and I seem to have found a problem when going from one page to another.

This is what my current model looks like:

```
define(['services/logger', 'services/dataService', 'durandal/plugins/router'],
function (logger, dataService, router) {
    var allModulesObservableCollection = ko.observableArray();
    var isInitialized = false;
    var activeSaIdParameter = "";

    var vm = {
        //bindable
        title: ko.observable(''),
        dataLoading: ko.observable(false),
        hasErrors: ko.observable(false),
        errorMessage: ko.observable(''),

        courseName: ko.observable(''),
        allModules: allModulesObservableCollection,

        //operations
        refreshData: refreshData,
        showActiveModules: showActiveModules,
        activate: activate,
    };

    return vm;

    function activate(context) {
        logger.log('All Modules View Activated', null, 'allModules', true);
        if (!isInitialized) {
            activeSaIdParameter = context.activeSaId;
            isInitialized = true;
            fetchModulesData(context.activeSaId);
            return fetchHeaderData(context.activeSaId);
        } else {
            if (context.activeSaId != activeSaIdParameter) {
                activeSaIdParameter = context.activeSaId;
                fetchModulesData(context.activeSaId);
                return fetchHeaderData(context.activeSaId);
            }
        }
    }


    function fetchModulesData(activeSaId) {
        vm.dataLoading(true);
        vm.hasErrors(false);
        return dataService.getAllModulesInCourse(activeSaId)
            .then(fetchModulesCompleted)
            .fail(fetchDataFailed);

        function fetchModulesCompleted(data) {
            allModulesObservableCollection(data);
            debugger;
            vm.dataLoading(false);
        }
    }

    function showActiveModules() {
        var url = '#/activeModules/' + activeSaIdParameter;
        router.navigateTo(url);
    }   
});
```

The first time around the data gets displayed correctly and everything works fine.But after going to another page and then trying to come back to this one , it's like the browser completly ignores the javascript code.

ShowActiveModules() is responsible for taking the user to it's sibbling page.

While debugging I noticed that after commming back to this page the browser does not even run this code anymore.I have to compleetly refresh the page for it to get the data and display it.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the html view also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't run through this file again as RequireJS only reads through the file once.

At first glance your 'activate' function should be getting called again though. Have you tried putting a breakpoint on **just** the 'activate' function?